# insufficient storage when installing a new app

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory

when I try to install an app which requires 22MB, it fails because of insufficient storage.

I check my system, it shows 652MB free internal storage, 251MB free SD card storage, and 460MB free RAM, Then why does installing the app fail? How should I free up space to allow the installation to succeed?

Thanks.

Comment: How much is your overall internal storage? Something around 6 GB? Then it's the 10% rule again. See our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details.